# ehcache in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ehcache

I want to achive Spring annotation based cache using `ehcache` to `cache some methods`.

I know the way how it works.

My question is to `resolve the dependency`.

I need to know is it `ehcache-core.jar` is enough to achieve method level cache ?

or we need whole `ehcache.jar` to achieve the same .

if anyone explain me the difference between those 2 jars and help me to choose best fit one it would be great help for me.

also my application is using `ehcahce-core with 2.4.1` already and

if i want to use `ehcache.jar` then i need to find the same version of `ehcahce.jar` which is bit challenging as i am currently not finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring annotation bases caching with EhCache support will work with either the `ehcache-core.jar` or `ehcache.jar` (one of my projects uses the first while another uses the other).

You can find all the versions of `ehcache.jar` [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache) and the versions of `ehcache-core.jar` [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core).